# redirect user if not logged into wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I need to redirect users not logged in to any page I choose. Not the login page. I tried placing this code in the header, but it is an endless loop. Anybody know what code I need? Thanks

```
<?php
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
 wp_redirect( 'http://skeeterz71.com/cyber/about/');
 exit; 
} ?>
```

Comment: do you have same redirect code on 'http://skeeterz71.com/cyber/about/ page also?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding some code in functions.php file

```
function user_redirect() {

    // Current Page
    global $currentpage;

    // Check to see if user in not logged in and not on the login page
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && $currentpage!= 'wp-login.php')
          // If user is, Redirect to Login form.
          wp_redirect( 'http://skeeterz71.com/cyber/about/');
}
// add the block of code above to the WordPress template
add_action( 'wp', 'user_redirect' );
```

Comment: yes this will work. but what if he is trying to redirect on about us page also? as he says its going in endless loop.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong. I added the code copy and paste into functions.php and still it is a continuous loop according to ff and chrome.

Comment: Do I add this to the header maybe? // add the block of code above to the WordPress template
add_action( 'wp', 'user_redirect' );

Comment: Redirect loops can be caused by redirects in an .htaccess file or by redirection plugins. did you add any redirection plugin @user1951143

Comment: do a check for about us page as i have showed in my reply

Comment: if no plugin install then main couse may be in your .htaccess file, try to restore it

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same redirect code on about us page, you can put a check like below

```
<?php
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

if(!is_page('about'))
 wp_redirect( 'http://skeeterz71.com/cyber/about/');
 exit; 
} ?>
```

or, you can check for page template instead of is_page()

```
if(!is_page_template('page-about.php'))
     wp_redirect( 'http://skeeterz71.com/cyber/about/');
     exit;
```

Comment: Same problem. No plugins installed other than aksimet. This is a new install of wp.

Comment: Did u tried above code? this code u can try in header or u hook it wp

Comment: Yes I tried all these suggestions to no success. except the page template because I am not using a custom page template